# How do I import RSSfeed in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, rss

I want to import a RSS feed in Google App Script and save the "title" and "content" (= the main text of the RSS-feed) in seperate array's so that I can modify them and output the result in a Google Spreadsheet.

At the moment I import the RSS-feed in the sheet (with =ImportFeed) and read those cells and store them in an array, modify them and output it to new cells. This works, but it's slow (Google App Script getting data from Google Sheets is slow).

If I'm able to directly import the RSS-feed in the script this increases the speed of the process. But the problem is I don't know how, and can't find anny helpfull information (I'm teachning myself).

Maybe there is somebody who can help me, thanks!

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the actual data of RSS feed from your question, how about using [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) and [XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
function test() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("KEY").getSheetByName('SHEET_NAME');
// create a list of existing "IDs" for each post / comment, to avoid adding duplicates in the sheet
var temp = sheet.getRange(1, 6, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
var existingIds = [];
for (var i in temp) {
existingIds.push(temp[i][0]);
}

var feed = UrlFetchApp.fetch("RSS_URL.XML").getContentText();
feed = XmlService.parse(feed);
var items = feed.getRootElement().getChild("CHILD_NAME").getChildren("ITEM");

for (var i in items) {
var link = items[i].getChild("ITEM").getValue();
// avoid adding duplicates
if (existingIds.indexOf(link) != -1) continue;

var ITEM = items[i].getChild("ITEM").getValue(); 
var ITEM = items[i].getChild("ITEM").getValue(); 
var ITEM = items[i].getChild("ITEM").getValue(); 
var ITEM = new Date(items[i].getChild("ITEM").getValue()); 

sheet.appendRow([ITEM, ITEM, ITEM, ITEM, ITEM]);
}
}
```